# view shows as database overriding code

Tags: views, features

I've created a simple feature to export my custom views. I've downloaded the view and enabled it on the manage features screen. When I look at the view in views it tells me that the database is overriding code. I don't know why as I haven't touched the view since creating the feature. Surely the view should be 'in code'?

Answer (score 1):

Even if you don't change anything, it's enough to click the 'Save' button on the views configuration page to make it override the code. You can simply revert the view if you are sure that you didn't change anything.